# add value to each array item

Tags: php

I am trying to put a timeago in each post data inside an array , the post data are from mysql table. the code as follow:

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 8"; 
  $query = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());

  $count = 0; // Initialize counter
$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $query )) {
    $rows[++$count] = $row;
  }
```

The rows have been put into an array.
inside each there is : user , postcontent , time(which i use to calculate timegao)

timeago script as follows:

```
function timeago($time)  
    {  
    $periods = array("second", "minute", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "year", "decade");  
    $lengths = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10");  

    $now = time();

    $format = strtotime($time);
    $difference     = $now - $format;  
    $tense         = "ago";  

    for($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j] && $j < count($lengths)-1; $j++)   
        {  
        $difference /= $lengths[$j];  
        }  

    $difference = round($difference);  

    if($difference != 1)   
        {  
        $periods[$j].= "s";  
        }  

    return "$difference $periods[$j] $tense";  
    }
```

how do i loop through each array row , get the time out , calculate it using timeago function , then inject in the results as 'timeago':'value-calculated' into each array row?

Comment: you don't need `$rows = array();` statement. #Not-related-to-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like below, PS: `$counter` is not necessary.

```
$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $query )) {
  $row['timeago'] = timeago($row['time']);
  $rows[] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $query )) {
  $rows .= timeago($row['time']);
}
```